# "boot device not found" after manually changing grub.cfg for dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, grub-efi

I tried to dualboot window with Ubuntu for that i edited the `Grub.cfg` file just i added
[This the code I wrote there in Grub cfg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giTqy.jpg)

After that, i restarted my laptop and getting this kind of error as:
[Now laptop window shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikBFB.jpg)

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Welcome! could you provide what version/distro are u using inside your question, please? you have setted what config in sda/sdb devices? GPT ? MBR?.

Comment: @matthias lenmher I was using Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? You posted an old BIOS/MBR(msdos) boot stanza. New systems are UEFI as Microsoft has required vendors install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. And then Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode. You normally do not edit grub.cfg, but edit 40_custom.

Comment: @oldfred my system is UEFI, i actually watch a video from YouTube that how should I install window without any external media, so I made a different partition of NTFS in which the iso file(window 10) was extracted and then i edited the grub.cgf, after that when I restarted it shows as I posted above. Link for that video is:. 'https://youtu.be/1Y4JXv9r5Ug'

Comment: I do not watch videos. But Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives and only in BIOS mode from MBR partitioned drives. And if BIOS/MBR, the boot partition must be a primary partition with boot flag. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs & almost all systems now should be UEFI (at least since 2012).

Answer (score 0):

Mine looks like this:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-F024-2799' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  F024-2799
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F024-2799
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

and it works. So this is for a GPT based installation. If yours installation is GPT as well, I would suggest you change your config-file. ( The number of the root uuid you have to change in your number of course. For that see the entry of the "01 Header¨ or your "10_Linux_Proxy" in the config-file. ). You will have to do this with root privileges, otherwise you cannot change the file ( it is read only for normal user and read/write for root ). But this you probably knew, because you changed your file.

Comment: yeah this thing I know but am not able to access after the window is just showing to check memory etc.

Comment: Boot it up with your usb stick and then change the file. If that doesn't work reinstall Grub2.